# display settings inside a tab

Tags: android, settings

How can you display a settings dialog inside a tab or layout instead of showing it full screen?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: i haven't done any Settings yet. i'm asking in advance so i know if it can be displayed inside a tabview or if i have to do all settings like regular controls.